# Installing Domogik plugins(ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: software-installation

I trying to install plugins for Domogik home automation software,according to instructions,I enter this line in terminal , dmg_package --install https://github.com/domogik/domogik-brain-base/archive/1.4.zip , it returns this error , Domogik tool must be run with the user defined in /etc/default/domogik as DOMOGIK_USER : xxx.How can I change user to the required one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Logout and login as the correct user?

Comment: Tried your suggestion but no luck,I'm probably doing something wrong still. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Well, which user is defined in /etc/default/domogik?